# How to change background on hover for 2 elements using css

Tags: html, css

I'm having a time trying to solve this. I want to change the background of two child elements if the user hovers over the parent element.

Here is what that image looks like using the code I currently have. What is should look like on hover is an all brown image, no blue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXS34.jpg]

The HTML:

```
    <div id="nav-about" class="nav-btn">
      <h2>About Us</h2>
      <div class="nav-btn-lt"></div>
      <div class="nav-btn-rt"></div>
    </div>
```

The nav-btn class uses a repeating x background, the nav-btn-lt class is a shadow that unfortunately I couldn't reproduce using css, and the nav-btn-rt class is the image I cannot get to show on hover.

Here is the CSS:

```
 .nav-btn {
  position:relative;
  width:22%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:110px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:11px 2% 0 0;
  border-top:2px solid #EFFFFF;
  border-bottom:2px solid #1F3152;
  background:url(bg-btn-off.gif) repeat-x;
  }

  .nav-btn:hover {
  background:url(bg-btn-on.gif) repeat-x;
  }

  .nav-btn h2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  font-size:150%;
  font-weight:600;
  color:#eee;
  }

  .nav-btn-lt {
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  left:0;
  width:2px;
  height:114px;
  background:url(lt-nav.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  }

  .nav-btn-rt {
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  right:0;
  width:54px;
  height:114px;
  background:url(rt-nav-off.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  }
```

Is it possible to change the images on both child elements upon hovering over the parent element?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Jatin.

Comment: Something like `.nav-btn:hover > div:first-child {hover-bg}` and `.nav-btn:hover > div:last-child {hover-bg}`

Comment: Thanks misterManSam. I'll give this a go. I thought this was going to be a little more complex. Glad to see it was an easy fix.

Comment: You will probably need to make some changes elsewhere in your CSS as well. `.nav-btn:hover > div:first-child` will select the first div child of the button only where that first div is a direct child element of `.nav-btn`. You can, of course, target the classes as well like the answer below :)

Comment: Actually, your first rule works right out of the box. I can't believe it was this easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You target the parent's hover state and add any child elements you want their attributes modified.

```
.nav-btn:hover .nav-btn-lt,
.nav-btn:hover .nav-btn-rt {
    background: blue;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0zqm0bd7/1/

Comment: Jerry, I just had a look at your site and wanted to ask... Who does your graphic design work? It's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

## Slightly different idea

Here is an idea that uses less HTML; it leaves the CSS to do all the styling.

The inner divs are replaced with [`:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

### Example

In this example, both pseudo elements have different background image colors. These would be replaced with your background images, along with the widths and heights modified to suit.

- The pseudo elements are targeted on hover with `.nav-btn:hover:before`/ `:after`
- The `position: relative` on `h1` ensures that it is displayed above the background.

"Run code snippet" to see the result:

```css
.nav-btn {
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 2px solid #EFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1F3152;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s border;
}
.nav-btn h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #212121;
  transition: 0.5s color;
}
.nav-btn:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/180X110/ffeb3b ) no-repeat;
}
.nav-btn:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/20X110/fff59d  ) no-repeat;
}
.nav-btn:hover {
  border-color: #fb8c00;
}
.nav-btn:hover h1 {
  color: #f3e5f5;
}
.nav-btn:hover:before {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/180X110/9c27b0) no-repeat;
}
.nav-btn:hover:after {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/20X110/ab47bc ) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-btn">
  <h1>Hover Us</h1>
</div>
```